# JavaFX program start takes 12 Seconds when online

Tags: java, javafx-2

I made a simple "Hello World" app from the E(fx)clipse Tutorial 1.

When starting the jar from the dist folder, my system took more than 12 Seconds. I verified that with the oracle sample apps, which behave identical.

Start up time is less than a second when I disable Wifi, thus no internet connection available. Running a Windows 7 (64 Bit) machine with Java x86, Version 7.

Is this a personal problem or can I expect this behavior on all machines where the app is deployed? Then JavaFX would be useless. Swing jars start instantly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely the proxy resolution which was fixed with https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=408397. If you are not on the nighlty tooling (http://downloads.efxclipse.bestsolution.at/downloads/nightly/sdk) you'd have to modify the build.xml by hand adding "<attribute name="JavaFX-Feature-Proxy" value="None"/>" to the <manifest> tag

Comment: I installed efxclipse just today. And the entry is actually there. Also note, that the oracle sample programs take the same start up time.

Comment: So you say the value is part of the manifest but performance is still bad. Is performance also so bad in the IDE? The wifi stuff really points to proxy stuff.

Comment: Did you try the command line param mentionned in https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/packaging_improvements_in_jdk_7#4

Comment: I noticed the following behavior: "java -jar -Djavafx.autoproxy.enable test.jar" takes 12 seconds, "java -jar -Djavafx.autoproxy.disable test.jar" takes 1 second. Also "java -jar -Djavafx.autoproxy.disable=false test.jar" or "java -jar -Djavafx.autoproxy.disable=senseless test.jar" only take a second. Maybe the parameter has changed, because oracle says differently at "http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/troubleshooting.htm". IDE run starts fast.

Comment: Could you please start with -Djavafx.verbose=true with the jar

Comment: The time is lost between these: "launchApp: Try calling com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication -->Autoconfig of proxy is completed." I checked the build.xml, it contains "<attribute name="JavaFX-Feature-Proxy" value="None"/>"

Comment: Can you also check the MANIFEST.MF of the jar? It still thinks proxy conf is needed, maybe I'm doing something wrong on the jar gen?

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0,
JavaFX-Version: 2.2,
implementation-vendor: None,
javafx-feature-proxy: None,
implementation-title: Hello World,
implementation-version: 0.1,
JavaFX-Application-Class: myApp.MyApplication,
JavaFX-Class-Path: ,
Created-By: JavaFX Packager,
Main-Class: com/javafx/main/Main

Comment: So why on earth is that lowercase that's the problem

Comment: Grrr - please update to latest Java7u40 - this is a bug in the jfxpackager - see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/2col/fx2240-bugfixes-2007741.html and https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-25003

Answer (score 0):

The cause was wrong packing by Java 7, Version 25. Upgrading to Version 40 solved the problem.

As tomsontom pointed out, the manifest contained "javafx-feature-proxy: None" instead of "JavaFX-Feature-Proxy: None".